# Apache Gora over HBase

Tags: java, apache, nested, hbase, gora

We are planning to implement data warehouse based on HBase.

There are multiple entities which has Parent child like relation or in other words we have nesting.

```
public class Parent {

private String name;

private List<Dependent> dependents;
...
}
```

As per HBase, we can store these nested entities as value [as json / avro] in one of columnFamily.

We are looking at Phoenix for real time querying, I came across Apache Gora as one of the option.
As per documentation Apache Gora provides a nested entities but there is limited examples & documentation.

Does anyone have examples or experience with Apache Gora over HBase

Answer (score 0):

I have some development notes at http://people.apache.org/~alfonsonishikawa/gora-174.html and http://people.apache.org/~alfonsonishikawa/gora-174-notes.html (sorry if they are not very clarifying).

First of all, if I am not wrong, Apache Gora is not integrated into Apache Phoenix and I believe your necessities will not be covered.

Anyway, about your question regarding nested entities, Gora serializes de dependent entity and puts it into a column.
When you have a List/Array of dependents like in your example, each dependent entity goes into a column of a family. The negerated column name is the index.
When you have a Map of dependets, each entity goes into a column of a family, and the column name is the key of the dependent entity in the map.

Additionally, The fact that de data is serialized implies that you can't query on their content.

I hope this resolve your doubts, but if you have any other question just ask it :)